# Read a list of the application instances and versions using Inno Setup from registry?

Tags: inno-setup

I am busy writing an update installer for Inno Setup whereby I promt the user with the versions of my application that is currently installed and the current version of the application that will be installed using the installer.
To get the app version that will be installed I use the Inno Setup preprocessor directives:

```
#define MyAppVersion GetVersionNumbersString('{#MyAppExeName}')`

[Setup]
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppName}{#MyAppVersion}
```

The part I am struggling with is to get a list of all the versions of my application that is installed under myApps. I am thinking of using the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{}` with some wildcard to only give the names and versions of my app. Also to note, I have different appid's for the different versions of the app. Still manually doing my version installers, but will automate that in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RegGetSubkeyNames`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_reggetsubkeynames) to enumerate the keys.

```pascal
var
  I: Integer;
  Names: TArrayOfString;
  AppId: string;
begin
  if RegGetSubkeyNames(
       HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', Names) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Names) - 1 do
    begin
      if Copy(Names[I], Length(Names[I]) - 3, 4) = '_is1' then
      begin
        AppId := Copy(Names[I], 1, Length(Names[I]) - 4);
        { ... }
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```